# Issue using kernel linked list in user space

Tags: c, linux, linked-list

I have a linked list like this. The problem i am facing is i have initialized the list head and then i am doing `malloc` for that struct object.
What i need is i want to make `struct nsds_st *r` as head of linked list and other nodes after it.

```
 #ifndef __LIST_H
 #define __LIST_H

struct list_head {
        struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
typedef struct list_head st_list_head;


#define INIT_LIST_HEAD(ptr) do { \
        (ptr)->next = (ptr); (ptr)->prev = (ptr); \
} while (0)

/*
 * __list_add: insert new between prev and next.
 */
static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new,
                              struct list_head *prev,
                              struct list_head *next)
{
        next->prev = new;
        new->next = next;
        new->prev = prev;
        prev->next = new;
}

/**
 * list_add: add a new entry to the end of the list.
 */
static inline void list_add1(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
        __list_add(new, head->prev, head);
}

/*
 *__list_del: making the prev/next entries point to each other.
 */
static inline void __list_del(struct list_head *prev, struct list_head *next)
{
        next->prev = prev;
        prev->next = next;
}

/**
 * list_del: deletes entry from list.
 */
static inline void list_del(struct list_head *entry)
{
        __list_del(entry->prev, entry->next);
        entry->next = (void *) 0;
        entry->prev = (void *) 0;
}

/**
 * list_empty: check is list is empty.
 */
static inline int list_empty(struct list_head *head)
{
        return head->next == head;
}


/**
 * list_entry: retrieve the container struct.
 */
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
        ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))

/**
 * list_for_each: traverse through the list.
 */
#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
        for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); \
                pos = pos->next)

/**
 * list_for_each_delete: traverse through the list with safe delete
 */
#define list_for_each_delete(pos, n, head) \
        for (pos = (head)->next, n = pos->next; pos != (head); \
                pos = n, n = pos->next)
#endif


In my main file i have a structure like this

typedef struct nsds_s {
   // struct nsds_s *link;
    char client_id[18];
    char nguid[56];
    char mac[18];
    short int machine;
    cbt_list_head list;
}nsds_st;


nsds_st* nvmar_reply_packet (nsds_st *ptr)
{
    char cmd[500];
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    int num_rows;
    nsds_st *r=NULL,*temp=NULL;
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&r->list);   // i have intialized the head here

    sprintf(cmd, "SELECT * FROM ABCD_TABLE WHERE MACHINE = %.4x", ptr->machine);
        /* Running the sql query to check for fields with value in database */
    if (mysql_query(g_db_ctxt.db_handle.nsds, cmd)) {
        FINISH_WITH_ERROR(g_db_ctxt.db_handle.nsds);
        num_rows = -1;
        goto done;
    }
    result = mysql_store_result(g_db_ctxt.db_handle.nsds);
    if (result == NULL) {
        NVMAR_ERROR("Select Query Failed");
        FINISH_WITH_ERROR(g_db_ctxt.db_handle.nsds);
        num_rows = -1;
        goto done;
    }
    num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {
        r= (nsds_st *)malloc(sizeof(nsds_row_st));
        memcpy(r->registered_hosts,row[5],strlen(row[5])+1);
        memcpy(r->client_id,row[0],strlen(row[0])+1);

        //list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
       // list_add1(&temp->list,&r->list);  //it will go wrong here, i want to make r(structure r as head and then add other strutcure objects)  
     //   r->link = NULL;
        //list_add1(r, ptr);
#if 0
        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            temp =r;
            ptr=r;
        }
        else {
            temp->link = r;
            temp = temp->link;
        }
#endif

    }
done:
    mysql_free_result(result);

    return r;

}
```

Comment: Identifiers starting with`__` (double underscore) are reserved for the implementation by the C standard. **Do not use** them for user code!

Comment: At the beginning of `nvmar_reply_packet`, you set `r` to `NULL` and then dereference it in the next line with `r->list`.  What is `nsds_row_st` anyway? And why do you initialise your (circular?) list with a dummy node and not with `NULL`?

Comment: @MOehm updated the code

Comment: This is still too much code. You have problems when inserting a node. Cut the SQL stuff and reduce the list to a simple payload, maybe just an int. The node deletion and iteration macros aren't used and therefore just viaual noise for anyone trying to understand your code.

Comment: That said, I think the design of your list is flawed. An empty list shouldn't have a dummy node, but if it must have a dummy node, it should be allocated like all other nodes. Do you really need a double-linked list? You just append items at the moment and probably want to traverse it going forwards only.